# How to add an onclick event from an iframe to its parent window in plain JS?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

I'm trying to add an `onclick` event to a link, from inside an iframe. The link is located in the parent window of the iframe. The following code is what I'm using, but I'm getting an Exception. I'm testing on Firefox 9.0.1

```
function creaURL(url){
    //Some code to generate the string cadenaURL and give it the right format, it contains the data to pass
    this.location.href = url + '?' + encodeURIComponent(cadenaURL);
}

//This is where I'm adding the event to the link in the parent window
parent.document.getElementById("link7").onclick = function(){ creaURL("exercici7.htm") };
```

I've been able to make it work when the link is inside the iframe, but when the link is in the parent window, I just won't work. The Exception, in case it may be of some help:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 462"  data: no]

Comment: Are you developing a Firefox addon?

Comment: Hi, it's for a college assignment.
Right now I'm seeing that the word "this" in "this.location.href" is pointing to the object window, my fault. Will try will evt.target and report if I get any advancement.

Comment: Hi let me know where have you placed the function creaURL(). Is this function present in the Iframe or the parent window ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's in the iframe.

Comment: I've changed the event assignment to `parent.document.getElementById("link7").onclick = creaURL;`
And now I can use the word "this" in the right context inside creaURL(), to get the page address from inside the function with this.href.
The problem I'm facing now, is how to use this line so it works, `location.href = this.href + '?' + encodeURIComponent(cadenaURL);`, I don't know how to attach it to the link that has called the function creaURL().

Comment: Hey can you paste the content of your parent window?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the interest. After a few more tries using Firebug to inspect the DOM attributes I finally got it, I removed the last line inside creaURL and replaced it with `this.href += '?' + encodeURIComponent(cadenaURL);`

No more Exceptions, everything is running fine now and the data gets transferred correctly.